# Const int to int doesnt work properly

Tags: c, constants, mplab

If I convert `const int` to `int` inside a `void` it works.
But when I create an `extern const int` it doesn't.

```
void ReadFromEpprom()
{
  int Start = 343;
  const int End=Start; //This works
}
```

Example 2

Header File

```
extern const int End;
```

Source file

```
const int End;

void ReadFromEpprom()
{
  int Start = 343;
  End=Start; //This doesn't work
}
```

In second situation I get error:

> (364) attempt to modify object qualified const

How can I solve this?
Should I make it with another way?

Comment: Why are you trying to modify a constant, which is by definition immutable? http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html

Comment: Cause i need to read epprom value inside a variable and also this variable to be used in a array. Array accepts ony constant and Read value from epprom only int so i must convert one of them

Comment: If you want to modify `End` it can not be constant. And you can pass non-constant variables to functions declared as taking `const` arguments. If that's your problem.

Comment: So keep the variable mutable until it doesn't need to be? At insertion, assign it to a constant.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Tell us more about your _actual_ prblem.

Comment: The `const int` is actually working exactly as it's supposed to. I wouldn't rush to blame your implementation.

Comment: I cant make global variable const int?

Comment: You can make a global variable const, but you can't change it. That's what `const` means.

Comment: Initialization is not assignment. These are different terms and the programmer must be aware of the difference. (Particularly if you end up using higher-level languages than C.)

Comment: How can i pass an int value into an array? Array works only with constant

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `End` as the size of an array? That's not a problem since C supports [variable-lenght arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: edit question and add ">" to get yellow box for your error.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a constant variable this means the variable will not change.So it makes sense that constant variables must be initialized immediately.You are doing this in your first example which is correct.In your second example you have a constant variable and then you are trying to modify it's value.This is incorrect since the variable is already constant.

Answer (score 0):

The `extern` here is a red herring.

If you use `const int End` then you need to initialise `End` at the point of this declaration. That's because it's `const`.

So `const int End = Start;` works fine, but `const int End;` is not syntactically viable.

In C you can't arrange things so you have a `const` at global scope and a function that sets the value at run-time. But what you *could* do is embed the value in a *function* (as as `static`), and call that function to initialise and subsequently retrieve the value.

Comment: How can i make const int global? End to be used every where

Comment: @Dim: One pattern is to use a function, see the changes to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialiazation versus assignment:

A `const` object can be initialized (given a value at the declaration), but not assigned (given a value later).

---

This is initialization, and "works".  It is initialization the local variable `End` that exist inside `ReadFromEpprom()`.

```
void ReadFromEpprom()
{
  ...
  const int End=Start; //This works
```

---

`End=Start;` attempts to assigned `End` that exist at file scope, outside of `ReadFromEpprom()`.  `const` objects cannot be assigned.

```
const int End;

void ReadFromEpprom()
{
  ... 
  End=Start; //This doesn't work
}
```

---

> How can I solve this?

Let external code to read `localEnd` via a function `ReadEnd()`, yet allow local code to write `localEnd`.

```
static int localEnd;

int ReadEnd() {
  return localEnd;
}

void ReadFromEpprom() {
  int Start = 343;
  localEnd = Start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the other answers.

It seems that you want to initialize a `const` value with a value that will be determined at run time, which is **impossible**.

What you can do is two workarounds.

1. Remove `const`. Add a comment near its definition that the variable is set only once in the very beginning.
2. Use a function instead of a `const int` variable; implement the "run code only once" idea inside this function.

   Header file:

   ```
   int CalcEnd();
   ```

   Source file:

   ```
   int CalcEnd()
   {
       static int init_done = 0;
       static int result;
       if (!init_done)
       {
           result = 343; // or any complex calculation you need to do
           init_done = 1;
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

   Note how the function uses `static` variables and logic to do initialization only once.

If you use the function idea, and don't want to remember typing the parentheses in the function call (`CalcEnd()`), you can define a macro:

```
#define End MyCalcEnd()
```

This will make it appear as if `End` were `const int` variable, when actually it's a function call. This usage of macros is controversial, use it only if you are sure it will not lead to confusion later.